# SQL Server Concatenate using FOR XML dilemma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I come from an oracle background so in doing searches on this site I have found countless examples on how to use the FOR XML PATH to try to duplicate what LISTAGG() will do in oracle.  However I don't know if what I am trying to do is outside of that scope or I am not figuring out what piece I am missing. Every example I have found just uses a single key id and in my case I have to use joins from multiple tables.

Here is the layout for how the tables look.

```
CREATE TABLE driven_product
([PRODUCT_ID] int, [DRIVER_ID] int, [DRIVER_PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM] int);

INSERT INTO driven_product
([PRODUCT_ID], [DRIVER_ID], [DRIVER_PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM])
VALUES (1, 2, 3);

CREATE TABLE product_input
([PRODUCT_ID] int, [PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM] int, [PRODUCT_VALUE_NUM] int, [COLOR] VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO product_input
([PRODUCT_ID], [PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM], [PRODUCT_VALUE_NUM], [COLOR])
 VALUES
   (1, 3, 1, 'White'),
   (1, 3, 2, 'Blue'),
   (1, 3, 3, 'Green'),
   (1, 3, 4, 'Yellow'),
   (1, 3, 5, 'Orange');

CREATE TABLE driven_price
[PRODUCT_ID] int, [DRIVER_ID] int, [PRODUCT_VALUE_NUM] int, [PRICE] int);

INSERT INTO driven_price
([PRODUCT_ID], [DRIVER_ID], [PRODUCT_VALUE_NUM], [PRICE])
VALUES
   (1, 2, 1, 10),
   (1, 2, 2, 10),
   (1, 2, 3, 10),
   (1, 2, 4, 20),
   (1, 2, 5, 20);
```

The driven_product table joins to the product_input table using driven_product.product_id = product_input.product_id AND driven_product.driver_product_input_num = product_input.product_input_num.  The driven_price table joins using the 
driven_product.product_id = driven_price.product_id, driven_product.driver_id = driven_price.driver_id, and product_input.product_value_num = driven_product.product_value_num.

The closest I have gotten to is:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '/' + color
              FROM product_input pi
              WHERE pi.product_id = dp.product_id
              AND pi.product_input_num = dp.product_input_num
              FOR XML PATH( '')), 1, 1, ''), dpr.price
FROM driven_product dp
INNER JOIN driven_price dpr ON dp.product_id = dpr.product_id
AND dp.driven_id = dpr.driven_id
```

This combines all the colors into each price.

Now the obvious thing is that I am not joining the product_input.product_value_num to the driven_price.product_value_num.  When I do that it breaks each color out into its own row.

So this is where I am struggling is that I need to do it by price.  So I need to have "White, Blue, Green" and "Yellow, Orange" to be separate.

I tried to set this up on SQLFiddle, but I kept getting errors.  Any guidance that you can provide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group by or distinct.. but your main problem is you were not filtering your FOR XML query by PRICE, so you're getting every color.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Products = STUFF((
                SELECT '/' + color
                FROM    driven_price dp2
                        JOIN product_input pi ON dp2.Product_Value_Num = PI.Product_Value_Num
                WHERE   dp2.driver_id = dpr.driver_id AND dp2.Price = dp.Price
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
        dp.[Price]
FROM    driven_product dpr
        JOIN product_input pri ON dpr.Driver_product_input_num = pri.PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM
        JOIN driven_price dp ON pri.product_id = dp.product_id 
            AND pri.product_value_num = dp.product_value_num
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregation in the outer query.  I *think* this will do what you want:

```
SELECT dpr.price,
       (SELECT '/' + pi.color
        FROM product_input pi join
             driven_product dp INNER JOIN
             ON pi.product_id = dp.product_id AND
                pi.product_input_num = dp.product_input_num
        WHERE dp.product_id = dpr.product_id
        FOR XML PATH(''))
       )
FROM driven_price dpr
GROUP BY dpr.price;
```

**Note:**  You only need `stuff()` to handle infix separators.  If you are happy with "/blue/green/red", then you don't need it.  The purpose of `stuff()` is to remove a leading separated, so ",blue,green,red" becomes "blue,green,red".

Comment: Usually love your answers Mr Linoff, but I can't see that working at all.. :(
Everytime I try to run it as well I get an `incorrect syntax` error.
Modifying it as far as I can, brings back the problem of returning every colour for both prices.